# How do I programmatically show and hide a DIV by clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) How to programatically (without writing the onclick="javascript:.." attribute) attach JavaScript (jQuery) function to the link below?

2) The simplest way to toggle hide/unhide after clicking on the Statement link? First click should display the DIV (unhide), the second click should hide it and so forth.

```
<a>Statement</a>
<div id="taxStatement">insert select statement dropdownbox</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the link a class, for example:

```
<a class="toggle" href="#">Statement</a>
<div id="taxStatement">insert select statement dropdownbox</div>
```

Then attach script on `document.ready` with [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the element, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.toggle").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

You can initially hide the `<div>` in multiple ways, CSS:

```
#taxStatement { display: none; }
```

Or give it a class, e.g. `class="toggleDiv"` and hide them all the same way:

```
.toggleDiv { display: none; }
```

Or also in your `document.ready`, via script:

```
$(".toggleDiv").hide();
```

[You can give it a try/experiment here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8twRp/).

Comment: If I understand this right, it toggles the next div after the toggle link? If so, then this is great.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1 and 2, you'll want to use toggle:

```
$('a').toggle(
function () {
  // Unhide Statement
  $('#taxStatement').show();
},
function () {
  $('#taxStatement').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var theDiv = $('#taxStatement');

   theDiv.hide();
// make the div hidden by default.

   theDiv.prev('a').click(function(){ theDiv.toggle(); });
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Attach the onclick                 hide & unhide.
//  assume the <a> is 
//  immediately before that <div>.
// It may be better to give an
//  id to that <a>.
```